# Adding an icon to a Truecrypt/Veracrypt volume

Tags: windows-7, icons, truecrypt, autorun

I used an external hard disk with an Autorun.inf file in the root directory to assign a label and an icon to the volume. But now I encrypted it with Truecrypt, and when I mount it, the Autorun.inf doesn't work and the label and the icon doesn't appear. I have been able to assign the label using LABEL command from command prompt. However, I cannot assign the icon. Is there any way to assign the icon to the volume? Any help would be appreciated. Also, the solution should not be a registry tweak. The icon should appear, irrespective of the PC it is mounted on.

OS Used: Windows 7 Professional 32-bit